# Getting Console Messages on Webpage NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm wondering if there's any way to listen for console messages and act on console messages when they're received. Mainly, is there any way to do this without an external module, and using the `http` module?

The goal is to trigger a NodeJS function or code snippet on an event like `click` in the HTML. If there's also a way to do this, then that's great. But once again, I'd like to do this without an external module, and just use those that are built-in to NodeJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onclick()` function in JavaScript to trigger a function call when clicking on a element. Then use `fetch` to make a api call to the nodejs server.

Comment: How do you use fetch to make a call to NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

I know @Haris Wilson already got the answer, but I'd just like to provide a code example.

Instead of trying to catch a console message and then execute a function if we find it, we can use `fetch()` to make a request to whatever URL we need, and this can allow us to make other requests.

In this case, we can use the `url` module and the `http` module to parse the url and serve the API and website, respectively.

```
const url = require('url')
const http = require('http')

const requestListener = async function (req, res) {
     // Basic server setup
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });

    res.end(/** Content here */)

    // API 
    if (url.parse(req.url, true).pathname === '/APIcall') {
        let arguments = url.parse(req.url, true).query
        
        // Preform necassary actions here
    }
}
```

We can now use `onClick` to call a function inside our webpage JavaScript, and use `fetch([API URL])` to give our NodeJS data to preform an action. We can use URL params to do this, such as `https://localhost:8080/APIcall?data=someData&moreParam=more-data`, where `?data=someData&moreParam=more-data` are the URL params.